# The server failed to process the request. error in Visio

Tags: sharepoint-2010, visio

In my share point 2010 server i have 2 sites Port no 333,3002

if i add visio diagram in my 333 i display it perfectly but in 3002 site it gives "The server failed to process the request." error how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fix is to navigate to Central Administration -- Manage Service Applications --  Visio Graphics Services -- Global Settings and check the Application ID

Go back to Manage Service Applications -- Secure Store Services -- select the visio application id -- Set credentials

Once you set the username and password credentials, save and exit. This will fix the refresh and the visio graphics services error logged in the event viewer.

for more details check http://www.sathishtk.com/blog/post/2010/02/04/Visio-2010-Beta-Services-Error-The-server-failed-to-process-the-request.aspx